# Github Actions http request

Tags: github, git-push, git-commit, http-post, github-actions

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de hacer un **post request** mediante **github actions** una vez q se suben los cambios a mí repositorio. La idea es ejecutar un **git pull origin main** para que mí código en producción tomé los cambios sin tener q correr el comando manualmente, tengo un post preparado que ya ejecuta este comando, solo tengo q hacer el post y me encantaría saber si se puede hacer por github actions

Comment: Buscaste en Github Marketplace? Porque googleé y apareció de inmediato [http-request-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/http-request-action) que hace justo eso que dices.

Comment: perfecto, lo voy a testear